# Powerbi oauth api provides 403 while accessing data from access token

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to get the rest api working on the powerbi . I was successfully able to login using the grant type as client_credentials . Here is my request data while creating token .

```
{
 client_id:'my-client-id',
 client_secret:'my-client-secret'
 grant_type:'Client credentials' 
}
```

But when I use the response token from this api to get other api response . I get **403** error as a response when try to access the data . The following permission is given to my app but still I am getting 403 . Can anyone help me with this problem .[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you granted admin consent for these permissions by clicking the button bellow them:

[image]

Comment: That part is disabled in my account

Comment: Thanks for your suggesion