# AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '[Application Id]'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, powerbi

I am trying to embed power bi reports in my ASP.NET MVC application, In `AAD`, I have granted admin permissions to all the Power BI API and Graph API (User permissions specifically), but I keep getting this same error when trying to authenticate. I have set the `allowPublicClient` to true in the `manifest` as well.

Below is part of the code, but errors on the `authenticationResult` part:

```
    private static readonly string Username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pbiUsername"];
    private static readonly string Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pbiPassword"];
    private static readonly string AuthorityUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["authorityUrl"];
    private static readonly string ResourceUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["resourceUrl"];
    private static readonly string ApplicationId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["applicationId"];
    private static readonly string ApiUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiUrl"];
    private static readonly string WorkspaceId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["workspaceId"];
    private static readonly string ReportId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["reportId"];
    private static readonly string ReportId2 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["reportId2"];

        var result = new EmbedConfig();
        try
        {
            result = new EmbedConfig { Username = username, Roles = roles };
            var error = GetWebConfigErrors();
            if (error != null)
            {
                result.ErrorMessage = error;
                return View(result);
            }

            // Create a user password cradentials.
            var credential = new UserPasswordCredential(Username, Password);

            // Authenticate using created credentials
            var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(AuthorityUrl);
            var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ResourceUrl, ApplicationId, credential);
```

Besides for the `applicationId`, `workspaceId` and `reportIds`, I am using the following in my `web.config`:

```
<add key="authorityUrl" value="https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize/" />
<add key="resourceUrl" value="https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api" />
<add key="apiUrl" value="https://api.powerbi.com/" />
```

What else can I be missing that I still need?

Comment: You mention you have "granted admin permissions". Can you share some details about what you mean by this? How did you grant the permissions? Were they granted on behalf of all users, or only on behalf of a specific user?

Comment: By "granted" you mean that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58245339/powerbi-oauth-api-provides-403-while-accessing-data-from-access-token/58251993#58251993

Comment: I went into AAD and went to app registrations, selected the specific registered app  and then went under API permissions and added the permissions there(and granted admin consent)

Comment: @AndreyNikolov - Yes, thats it.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you are using an account with tenant admin/global admin credentials when you grant admin consent in the application permissions.

If you're accessing an API like you said, try deleting the API permissions from the app registration and re-adding them. Make sure the API is exposed and the default scope is added.

Did you ever enter the username and password when you got this error? It may be worth trying for error isolation.

If you already have the right account permissions, there is something else you may need to try. You can go to User Settings and click "Manage how end users launch and view their applications."

[image]

You’ll be able to change the settings for Enterprise Applications in particular.

Remove the app, and be sure to log in once if you are a global admin (or ask a global admin to log in once)

If the settings above were okay, try this trick: This solution only applies to Enterprise Applications:
The global administrator just needs to browse to Azure AD, remove the app, and then log in to the app. With some apps it’s pivotal that the first person to log in is a global administrator, to make it possible for them to give admin permission in the first place.

Also, if this is by chance a multi-tenant app, it's possible that the resource discovered that the user needs to provide more consent, or needs to do conditional access, and it is throwing that error.

It seems that a lot of things can throw this error... This discussion may be useful as well: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi/issues/19

Comment: Thanks for all the effort you put into your answer. Ive tried everything you mentioned and Im still getting the same error. Ive even created a new App Registration, but still no change :( I checked the user Im using to log into `Azure` has the `Global Admin` role assigned. To mention, the PBI License is owned by our client, but they have given us their credentials. Could this be a reason, possibly ? I cant imagine it could though, as I am inserting their PBI Credentials in my `web.config` as well.

Comment: So sorry to hear that!  If they’re giving you credentials and those credentials give you access to the data then I don’t think that should be a problem.

Comment: Just to add what we tried(which worked), we created our own trial PBI license in our own azure subscription(So effectively same domain was used. ex. user1@company1.com for pbi license and AAD also uses xxxx@company1.com) - After giving admin consent, the reports worked. So my assumption is that you can not use a PBI license registered from a different domain to the one where the app is registered. My findings may be wrong, but this is all I could see might be the problem.